# Solving a symmetric banded linear system with Cholesky factorisation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, factorization

I'm trying to solve a linear system Ax=b, where A has been factorised by Cholesky decomposition, and A is stored using symmetric banded storage.

Given a symmetric, positive definite matrix, A, I've managed to implement a function that first transforms the matrix A into a symmetric banded format via the transformation `A[i,j] = Ab[i-j,j]` with `j <= i < min(n,j+1+p)` and `p` is the lower bandwidth. As an example, inputting A, we get output Ab

```py
  [[1, 1, 0],   Ab=[[1, 2, 3],
A=[1, 2, 4],      [1, 4, 0]]
  [0, 4, 3]]
```

I have also implemented a function that applies Cholesky decomposition to Ab. I now need to implement forward and backward substitution to the banded Cholesky matrix. Given `L` (banded Cholesky factorisation of Ab) and `b`, I need to solve Lx=b, and I have based my algorithm off of a non-banded forward-backward substitution algorithm that is tested and works.

My current banded algorithm is as follows, but I think my indices for the array slicing are wrong.

```py
(n,m) = L.shape

# forward sub
for j in range(m):
    m = min(j+1+p,n)
    x[j] = x[j]/L[0,j]
    x[(j+1):m] = x[(j+1):m] - L[(j+1):m,j]*x[j]

# back sub
for j in range(n-1, -1, -1):
    m = max(0,j-p)
    x[j] = x[j]/L[0,j]
    diagonal = np.fliplr(L).diagonal(n-j-1)[1:]
    x[m:j] = x[m:j] - np.flip(diagonal*b[j])
return x
```

---

## **EDIT**

I've updated the forward substitution algorithm to use a for loop instead of slicing.

```py
for j in range(n):
    c = min(j+1+p,n)
     x[j] = x[j]/L[0,j]
     temp = x[j]
     for i in range(j+1,c):
          x[i] = x[i] - L[(j+i),j]*x[j]
```

Testing this code using `A` (thus `p=1`), and `b` (row sum, so `x` should be a vector of ones)

```py
  [[12.0, 4.0, 0.0],   
A=[4.0, 2.0, -1.0],   b=[16.0, 5.0, 6.0]
  [0.0, -1.0, 7.0]]
```

Using non working symmetrically-stored algorithms we get the following outputs `L` (Cholesky factorisation) and `x`

```py
  [[ 3.46410162,  0,          0        ]
L=[ 1.15470054,  0.81649658  0         ]   x=[1,1,1]
  [ 0,         -1.22474487,  2.34520788]]
```

and the output of the forward substitution is `x_forward=[4.61880215,-0.40824829,2.34520788]`. Testing this now with the symmetrically stored algorithm we get the Cholesky factorisation we get

```py
L_sym=[[ 3.46410162,0.81649658,2.34520788]
       [ 1.15470054,-1.22474487,0        ]]
```

as expected, but the output of the forward substitution is `x_sym_forward=[4.61880215,-0.40824829,6]`
so my updated algorithm seems to compute the first two entries correctly but then fails to compute the final entry. I've yet to attempt fixing the back substitution algorithm.

Comment: See [ask]. You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details. Do your own debugging, such as printing intermediate values for a small known matrix.

Comment: @relent95 thanks! I'll update the question with the test case I've been using

Comment: Just print all indexes and values in a loop, and check them all. For example, ```L[(j+i),j]*x[j]``` should be ```L[i,j]*x[j]``` in your second forward substitution code, if your L is a *n* by *n* matrix. Also ```L[0,j]``` is wrong.

Comment: @relent95, thanks for this! Have tested `L[i,j]` instead, though nothing changes. L is also not necessarily an (n,n) matrix in the symmetric storage as it will only store the main diagonal and all lower diagonals. So L will be of size (p+1,n) for an (n,n) input, where p is the lower bandwidth (and +1 comes from the main diagonal). In the non-symmetric storage algorithm you divide by `L[j,j]` so it transforms to `L[0,j]` given the main diagonal is now stored in the 0th row.

Comment: If L is a banded matrix, you should use ```L[(i-j),j]```, instead of ```L[(j+i),j]```. You know all the rules. Please check EAGERLY.

Comment: @relent95 have tested, and unfortunately that doesn't work. While L is banded, that transformation is applied to the original symmetric matrix A to convert it to symmetric banded storage prior to Cholesky decomposition. I'm unsure if that same transformation applies here.

Comment: Enough! Last comment. Forget about A and Ab for now. Implement a forward substitution for a none-banded L correctly at first, testing it for a simple matrix, such as [[1 0 0], [2 3 0], [4 5 6]]. Then modify it for a banded L. See [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).